# apache2 proxy redirect configuration

Tags: apache

This has been asked a bunch of time I realize but I still can't seem to get it working.  Here is my situation.  I have 2 servers on my network.  Server A is public facing which hosts my website.  My second server also has apache running with a web application which I would like to access externally.  I am not exactly sure how to configure this.  My current config looks like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:2323
<VirtualHost *:2323>
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.7/ampache
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.7/ampache
    servername slave-1
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
</VirtualHost>
```

So I would like all traffic on **https://my_domain.xx:2323** to redirect to **192.168.1.7/ampache**

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /airsonic http://192.168.1.7:8088/airsonic
ProxyPassReverse /airsonic http://192.168.1.7:8088/airsonic
```